# After export or import Realm library can't find Realm Objects

Tags: android, realm, stetho

For export my realm file I am using the next code:

```
File exportRealmFile;
            exportRealmFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "default.realm");
getRealm().writeCopyTo(exportRealmFile);
```

After that I am trying to import this file. I open Android Monitor and push file onto the another device.

But when I want to get RealmObject, for example, StatObject I see the object size is 0. But I know the size isn't 0.

```
 RealmResults<StatObject> statObjects =
                                realmForThisThread.where(StatObject.class).findAll();
LOG.debug("Size "+statObjects.size());
```

I open Stetho and I do not see any objects! But before export I saw seven different realm objects. However, the library itself has the same size. What am I doing wrong?

I am trying to import realm file using:

```
        RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .name("Realmexport.realm")
                .assetFile(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getPath())
                .build();
       // Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
```

But nothing changed.

Import file:

```
File oldRealmFile = new File(getRealm().getPath());
File newFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM) ,"default.realm");
 FileOutputStream outputStream=null;
 FileInputStream inputStream=null;
 try {
     outputStream = new FileOutputStream(oldRealmFile);
     inputStream = new FileInputStream(newFile);
     byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
     int bytesRead;
     while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
        outputStream.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
     }
     outputStream.close();
     inputStream.close();
     }catch (IOException exc){
             exc.printStackTrace();
     }finally {
     }
```

This approach helps to import file but new file I can't use it. Because I don't see my Objects.

Comment: How are you importing the exported Realm? can you share the entire code? I suspect you're just opening a new Realm (hence the size 0) since you're not pushing the exported Realm in the correct location.


Alternatively, you can ship the exported Realm using the `assets` then specify it in the `RealmConfiguration` to be sure you're using the correct file.

`RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
    .assetFile("myExported.realm")
    .build();`

Comment: I did this using two ways: the first way - i found my Realm file in app package by Android Monitor and changed them; the second way I found my realm file, code:   File realmFile = new File(getRealm().getPath()) and then wrote new file using outputStream and InputStream. In both variants I see a new realm file, but I can't use it.

Comment: can you try the `assetFile` approach?

Comment: Nabil, I wrote above about this approach. File doesn't rewrite. I see the same file.

Comment: I added above how I can import file but I can't see my Objects after that import.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `assetFile` in a wrong way. You're referencing an internal device location `.assetFile(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getPath())` whereas the exported Realm should reside in the `assets` folder of your APK. Also specifying a `name` will create a new (empty) Realm.

Try the following configuration instead.

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().assetFile("myExported").build();
```

Your APK:

`└── src
    └── main
        ├── AndroidManifest.xml
        ├── assets
        │   └── myExported.realm
        ├── java
        └── res`

Comment: I can't add this file to asset folder because this directory have only read permission and limit 10 MB. I download new Realm file from Firebase and place it into the DCIM or cache it doesn't matter.

Comment: You need to ship the file `myExported.realm` inside the `assets` folder before you build your APK. Don't try to `adb push` the file after the APK is installed.

Comment: It makes no sense. My task is for users in real time to exchange realm databases, sending them to each other.

Answer (score 0):

```
.assetFile(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getPath())
```

should be

```
.directory(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM))
```